# Why does R shiny not recognize the variable when pulled from input?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm working on creating a shiny app in R that lets the user choose one of two variables and whether or not there is a trendline on the graph. The output should be a scatterplot with the chosen variable on the x-axis and a set variable on the y-axis. When I create the plot in ggplot for output, I used ggplot(mydata, aes(x=input$variable, y=set_variable)) + geom_point .... and the rest of my plot code. However, when I run the app, the plot does not recognize the variable input as an actual variable in my data despites using the same name in the choices for the input. How can I fix this?

Comment: Try `aes(x=.data[[input$variable]], y=set_variable)`. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.